# Send javascript object to a spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, dictionary

Is it possible to send this kind of object to a Spring Controller?

```
{
   {test: [1,2,3,4]},
   {test1: [3,5,6,7]},
}
```

If possible what data type should I use? or is there any javascript data type or object that is possible to receive as map object on Spring controller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can create java object with the very same structure and then use @RequestBody in spring controller parameter.

@RequestBody will find json library on classpath and automatically convert your json to java object.

Take a look at google examples.. like http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody-demystified.html